# Is there any private README file writer where I can keep my private notes without using heavy-weight document writers?

Tags: github, webservice

I am looking for a notepad in the cloud to use as my reference book, so I can search by content and file name and edit. My best FREE notepad for the moment:

- edit
- add new
- read as raw (much cleaner to me)
- but can not make as string filenames
- can't search
- everybody can view it
- and also its not FREE

https://gist.github.com/

Is there anything I can use to keep such TUI notes (simple coder mind and clean  code book as private) with my source code and hints, etc.?

Readable as like this: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt  (clean and fresh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a private **[posterous](http://posterous.com)** space ?
You can add, edit, search, it's password protected, free, and handles
[syntax highlighting](http://posterous.com/help/markdown) for code snippets or just plain [gist insertions](http://blog.posterous.com/posterous-now-supports-traileraddict-embeds-a).

Comment: posterous is dead?

Comment: yep, long time dead